# How to count values in a nested array using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to calculate the unique count of `users.hobbies` using `Lodash`. The data looks like this:

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'hobbies': ['soccer','basketball']  },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'hobbies': ['soccer', 'golf'] },
  { 'user': 'tom',   'age': 25,  'hobbies': ['golf'] }
];
```

I have tried:

```
_.countBy(users, 'hobbies');
// { 'soccer,basketball': 1, 'soccer,golf': 1, golf: 1 }
```

The desired output is:

```
// { 'soccer':2, 'basketball':1, 'golf':2}
```

I guess I would need to `split` the value of `users.hobbies` but I am not exactly sure how to apply it.

Comment: Use: `_.countBy(_.flatten(users.map(u => u.hobbies)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flatten the hobbies before:

```js
const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'hobbies': ['soccer','basketball']  },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'hobbies': ['soccer', 'golf'] },
  { 'user': 'tom',   'age': 25,  'hobbies': ['golf'] }
];

const count = _.countBy(users.flatMap(user => user.hobbies));
console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about lodash, but here is solution with native js

```
users.reduce((total, el) => {
    el.hobbies.forEach(el => {
        if (el in total) total[el]++
        else total[el] = 1
    })
    return total
}, {})
```